# Нелегкий это труд (  )учеба.

Tags: пунктуация

Нелегкий это труд( )учеба.

> Как вы думаете, какой знак необходимо поставить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В исходном примере используется приложение "учёба". Оно стоит в конце предложения, конкретизирует подлежащее "труд", труд (какой?)- учёба. поэтому перед ним ставится тире. Сказуемое здесь составное именное - "нелёгкий".

Справка из ***Розенталя***: "Вместо запятой при обособлении приложений употребляется тире:
а)     если перед приложением можно без изменения смысла вставить слова «а именно», например: Утвержден новый государственный флаг Российской Федерации – трехцветное полотнище с белой, синей и красной продольными полосами;
б)     перед распространенным или ***одиночным*** приложением, стоящим ***в конце*** предложения, если *подчеркивается самостоятельность* или дается ***разъяснение*** такого приложения, например: Я не слишком люблю это дерево – осину (Тургенев); Объехали какую-то старую плотину, потонувшую в крапиве, и давно высохший пруд – глубокую яругу, заросшую бурьяном выше человеческого роста (Бунин); Рядом помещалась каморка – хранилище каталогов (Гранин);Стоял чудесный апрельский день – лучшее время в Арктике... (Горбатов)".